# Restart the OpenShift application mean reset it?

Tags: java, tomcat, restart, openshift

I have deployed my java application to OpenShift Online which running Apache Tomcat using this source (https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/openshift-tomcat-quickstart)

Every thing worked fine but when I restart the Tomcat through OpenShift Online console, the restart process done, but why my java applications, my configurations disappeared, just like everything gone back to the first time when I installed the Apache Tomcat :|

What's the problems? Please help me out!

Answer (score 0):

How did you deploy and configure your applications? In OpenShift, all deployments and configurations should be done **via the local git repository**. Any other deployment method is likely to be overridden.

Comment: I don't know what the problem but I've tried to deleted the App, re-created app and done anything via rhc and git and... It's worked :D
I'll try it again. I am  not enough Reputation to Vote, so sorry Robin.